# Expo SDK 39 custom channel with local notifications

Tags: android, notifications, expo

How do you use a custom channel with a local notification in Expo SDK 39 with Android?

On the topic of notifications, the Expo documentation seems to include a mishmash of instructions for both depreciated and the current version of Expo.

The documentation for [LegacyNotifications](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/legacy-notifications/#localnotification) mentions that a “LocalNotification” object can include configuration for “channelId”.

And, in fact, the legacy methods are what the current [notification guide](https://docs.expo.io/guides/notification-channels/) says to use:

```
Notifications.presentLocalNotificationAsync({
  title: 'New Message',
  body: 'Message!!!!',
  android: {
    channelId: 'chat-messages',
  },
});
```

But, in multiple places, the documentation says to NOT use the legacy methods:

[“This API is deprecated and will be removed in the SDK 40. Please, check the new notification module.”](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/legacy-notifications/)

[“Instead of presentNotificationAsync developers are encouraged to use setNotificationHandler and scheduleNotificationAsync.”](https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/master/presenting-notifications-deprecated.md)

Using the current API, I’m able to create a custom channel, ‘messages’, using “setNotificationChannelAsync”:

```
if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync('messages', {
      name: 'Messages',
      importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
      vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
      lightColor: '#FF231F7C',
    });
  }
```

The documentation gives the following simple example for using “scheduleNotificationAsync”:

```
async function schedulePushNotification() {
  await Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
    content: {
      title: "You've got mail! ",
      body: 'Here is the notification body',
      data: { data: 'goes here' },
    },
    trigger: { seconds: 2 },
  });
}
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#schedulenotificationasyncnotificationrequest-notificationrequestinput-promisestring), the only argument that “scheduleNotificationAsync” takes is “NotificationRequestInput,” which in turn can include “NotificationContentInput”. However, I did not see any mention of channelId.

Is there a way to use a custom channelId in scheduleNotificationAsync?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Folks on the [Expo forums](https://forums.expo.io/t/how-do-you-use-a-custom-channel-with-a-local-notification/44132/4) pointed out that `NotificationRequestInput` includes both `NotificationContentInput` and `NotificationTriggerInput`. The documentation for the [NotificationTriggerInput](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v39.0.0/sdk/notifications/#notificationtriggerinput) types includes channelId.

Expanding upon the example for `scheduleNotificationAsync`, the simplest use of `channelId` would be

```
  async function schedulePushNotification() {
    await Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
      content: {
        title: "You've got mail! ",
        body: "Here is the notification body",
        data: { data: "goes here" },
      },
      trigger: {
        seconds: 2,
        channelId: "messages",
      },
    });
  }
```